# Resharper: Rename all fields in the class

Tags: c#, resharper

**Possible duplicate:**
[resharper-or-coderush-global-rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414078/resharper-or-coderush-global-rename)

The duplicated question was asked about 3 years ago. So I want to know if there is any way to rename all fields in the class rather than renaming them one at a time because I have about 500 fields in 20 classes ? It will take a lot of time renaming them one at a time.

For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static string field_One = "one";
    public static string field_Two = "two";

    /*and so on. About 500 fields */
}
```

I need this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static string fieldOne = "one";
    public static string fieldTwo = "two";

    /*and so on. About 500 fields */
}
```

Comment: Two thoughts: 1) would per-file-replace on `field_` => `field` (and then review the changes) suffice? and 2: public static fields? ouch

Comment: If possible, go with the simplest way: Use a plain old Visual Studio replace with a regular expression.

Comment: ^^ Remembering of course that this will potentially affect the entire project. Find and replace like that can be restricted to a per document basis i think, might be safer to do it one doc at a time to not risk screwing it up elsewhere

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791762/resharper-rename-fields

Comment: Visual Studio supports vertical box selection (hold down Alt key while selecting). Do the vertical selection and then a search-and-replace within the selected text. It's not ReSharper and only works in certain scenarios, but it may accomplish what you desire.

Comment: Starting from R# 8, you can fix issues in a certain scope (incl the entire solution) http://stackoverflow.com/a/34528539/48953

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Resharper 2017.1 now supports Bulk Rename features. The "Alt-Enter" Rename suggestion has a menu flyout that gives you additional options (rename in file, folder, etc).

Comment: This is the right answer. It was added in ReSharper 9 and very handy to fix all naming convention violations in a file/folder/project/solution.

Comment: I've seen this and it's great, but I'm curious... is there a way to assign to a shortcut key?

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to do this with the Code Cleanup which can take the names of fields,props and methods and change them to suit the coding style defined in the profile. Ctrl-Alt-F

---

Unfortunately Resharper will only signal that the fields are not named according to the set naming convention and Code Cleanup doesn't include this check so it's not automated. The best you can do is learn the Hotkeys, enable static code analysis and go through each of them and use the action suggested by resharper to change to the correct name but this means you will surely get carpal tunnel by the end of it but the advantage is anyone can do it since you just have to hit the same sequence of keys repeatedly :P. - Check this stack question for hotkeys [Resharper function to fix naming convention issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864556/resharper-function-to-fix-naming-convention-issues)